# sticky note in HTML with edit

Tags: html, sticky

I'm trying to have a sticky note or some kind were people can type something in a text area and it gets saved on the server once your press save or something. People can edit the sticky note or add something else on it. Its just for the starting page of the company I'm working for.

Anyone has a clue if this is possible and/or how to do this?

Edit: You don't have to write the full code, if you could give me an idea/tell me if this is possible it would help a lot already.

Comment: For a start, the tag [sticky] has nothing to do with a sticky note. Read the description. Also, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You are expected to at least try and do it yourself, and if you run into a specific problem you can ask us.

Comment: Have you tried to write something already? You're more likely to get help if you post your attempts, rather than asking someone to do all the work for you. For example, a better question might be, "I've created my sticky note, but the users can't move it around. How would I accomplish that?" with a sample of your code to create the sticky note.

Answer (score 0):

You can get you desire result just by using textarea tag and just give it some stylesheet like "Sticky Note"

Use this css

```
.sticky-note {
    height: 211px;
    width: 894px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #feffdd;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

This will give your textarea look and feel like sticky note

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But I want to be enable to save text in it, I will check out this design though!

Comment: but no save for other visitors